# Angular - See variable change in parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback

Basically I have a form which is the parent component. This form is composed of a child component.

In order to disable a button I check a variable (datasetList[i].fileValid) with a function *isDatasetFilesValid()*. 
The variable is changed in the child component.

However, this change is done in a callback when I parse the file with papaparse and because it's done in a callback the parent doesn't see it.I know that because if I change the variable outside of the callback the button is available.

This variable is checked to be sure that a file has been selected.

Therefore I tried to add "detectChanges()" but it does not work.

**Parent component:**

```
   export class ExperimentCreateComponent implements OnInit {

     datasetList: any = [{ fileValid: false }];

     isDatasetFilesValid() {
       let index = this.datasetList.findIndex(function(item, i) {
       return item.fileValid == false;
       });
      let test = index === -1 ? true : false;
      console.log("Dataset", index + " -> " + test);
      return test;
      }
    }
```

**Parent html:**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">

        <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid" #f="ngForm" novalidate>


              <app-creation-dataset [datasetList]="datasetList"></app-creation-dataset>

                <button mat-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!isDatasetFilesValid()" (click)="createExperiment()">Submit</button>


        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Child Component:**

```
export class CreationDatasetComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() datasetList: any = [{ fileValid: false }];
  fileSelected: File;


  constructor(private papa: Papa, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onChange(files: FileList, index: number, dom: any) {
    // Option to parse the file with papaparse
    let options = {
      header: true,
      error: (err, file) => {
        this.datasetList[index].fileValid = false;
        alert(
          "Unable to parse CSV file, please verify the file can be accessed and try again. Error reason was: " +
            err.code
        );
        return;
      },
      complete: (results, file) => {
        console.log("Parsed:", results, file);
        let filename = file.name;

        // Add the dataset to the datasetList
        this.datasetList[index].headers = results.meta.fields;
        this.datasetList[index].values = results.data;
        this.datasetList[index].filename = filename;
        this.datasetList[index].is_metadata = false;
        this.datasetList[index].fileValid = true;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    };
    this.fileSelected = files[0]; // Get the file
    // Call the function to parse the file, option is the callback
    this.papa.parse(this.fileSelected, options);
  }
}
```

**Child HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let dataset of datasetList; let index = index">
  <div id="datasetFiles">
    <h6>Select the type of dataset and browse the files:</h6>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-6 d-flex align-items-center">
          <input id="file" #file (change)="onChange(file.files, index, $event.currentTarget)" type="file">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a subject to communicate between the components?

Comment: What do you mean by subject ?
Like a shared service ?

Comment: Exactly. If the Input decorator is proving difficult to use in this case, then using a shared service such as (on Angular's official documentation): https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service will allow you to do this with more control.

Comment: Yes I know I already use a service for some variable but I wanted to know if there was another way instead of creating a variable a variable in my shared service

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated. For what you need, the input decorator or cross component communication via a service will suffice. You're just trying to allow a component to detect a variable change in another component right?

Comment: Yes exactly!
But what is weird is that it works if it is not in the callback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174526/discussion-between-jburtondev-and-pierbjx).

Comment: @PierBJX Could you please show which line of code is not working?

Comment: In the child component.
When the line is this.datasetList[index].fileValid = true;
This works but it is not taken in account by the parent component. But if this line is outside the callback it works

Comment: @PierBJX Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No there is no error. I think it comes from the Lifecycle Hooks. It is not an error. It is just that the callback finishes after the onChange()

Answer (score 0):

Since your change is observed by the parent when the change is outside of the callback but not from the inside, it might be an issue with the context.

Try this:

```
  onChange(files: FileList, index: number, dom: any) {

    var that = this; // outer context

    // Option to parse the file with papaparse
    let options = {
      header: true,
      error: (err, file) => {
        this.datasetList[index].fileValid = false;
        alert(
          "Unable to parse CSV file, please verify the file can be accessed and try again. Error reason was: " +
            err.code
        );
        return;
      },
      complete: (results, file) => {
        console.log("Parsed:", results, file);
        let filename = file.name;

        // Add the dataset to the datasetList
        this.datasetList[index].headers = results.meta.fields;
        this.datasetList[index].values = results.data;
        this.datasetList[index].filename = filename;
        this.datasetList[index].is_metadata = false;
        that.datasetList[index].fileValid = true; // changed this to that
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      }
    };
    this.fileSelected = files[0]; // Get the file
    // Call the function to parse the file, option is the callback
    this.papa.parse(this.fileSelected, options);
  }
```